# Is there a better way to create asynchronous updates without using setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have multiple parts of my site which check for updates every half a second, so it can alert you of messages, etc. However I feel that using $.post with a setInterval could be a bit heavy on the site. Is there an alternative method that is better recommended for these tasks?

Comment: setInterval is definitely the best way to set asynchronous timed events. You say you have multiple parts, does each do it's own POST? That seems like it'd be the heavy part. Better to have one request get all the data.

Comment: You should really slow those requests down.  Firing off a HTTP request every half-second is too much.  20-30 seconds is a little more sane.  Using Web Sockets is ideal.

Comment: you can increase the interval so it won't take too much of your processing. here are methods under the term Comet http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking, however since the number of intervals depends on where you are on the page (asynchronous message updates, sidebar requests, various notifications, etc) So I'd have to modify it significantly based on what page you're on, however I may just end up doing it regardless because I think the extra work is well worth the increased respond time. Thank you.

Comment: Well I think the speed is important, especially when it comes to the chat-like message system, you need those updates to come as quickly as possible. However I could decrease the time alerts by a few seconds, it's still not very ideal.

Comment: @Ian: If it's something more time-sensitive, polling simply won't work.  You'll *need* to use long-polling or web sockets -- they're built for realtime communication.

Comment: @josh3736 Alright, looks like I'll just learn to use web sockets since this seems to be the prevailing recommendation, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[socket.io](http://socket.io/) would be the way to go if you're using [nodeJS](http://nodejs.org/). Otherwise, checkout [this jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-graceful-websocket/), it has graceful degradation implemented even though not as comprehensive as socket.io.

Comment: Nice plugin! Wouldn't you need some lightweight web server? A fat Apache/PHP process per user would pummel the server quickly...

Comment: Depends on the project, most early days websites probably just have 20-50 users at any single moment. And it doesn't mean you can't scale PHP, look at wordpress.com or facebook.

Comment: Sure you can scale PHP... I just suspect websockets and PHP/Apache don't mix any better than long polling and PHP/Apache. The short polling, sure, no problem.

Comment: Finally started learning this a couple weeks ago (about 4 months after you recommended it), I was shocked how much my site's performance increased.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, although it's not trivial.

**The better approach**

You can use long polling (or "comet"), which opens a connection, keeps it open for 20s or so, and the immediately re-opens it. The server can send something at any time.

Newer browsers provide websockets, which provides persistent connections.

Both are relatively complex to code so you need [some kind of framework](http://socket.io/) to handle things for you. Also, a connection needs to be kept open for each user, so it only really works with something lightweight like NodeJS.

**The easier approach**

If you want something easier to implement, I would recommend checking for updates as you suggested (it's called short polling to contrast it with long polling/websockets). You can do a simple polling solution like so:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
  // More lightweight than $.post
  $.get('/datasource', function () {
    /* do something */
  }); 
}, 3000);
```

3 seconds intervals [have been used in used before by high profile people](http://37signals.com/svn/archives2/launch_campfire_easy_group_chat_for_business.php).

If things get slow, try profiling database queries in /datasource

Comment: +1 -- Long polling/web sockets is really the proper way to do this.  Plus, [all the hard work is already done.](http://socket.io/)

Comment: Thanks for the link josh! Confirm this is a great framework, a very competent aquaintance of mine is using this successfully for some serious realtime stuff.